# Instalar email no meu debian 8

Tags: linux

Tenho instalado o Debian 8 e já consegui fazer um servidor web, agora preciso instalar o e-mail do meu domínio, como isso eu nunca fiz, gostaria de saber por onde posso **começar, para que eu consiga receber e enviar emails do meu domínio**, instalar SMTP, POP3 etc.

Comment: https://servidordebian.org/pt/stretch/email/start

Comment: @MagicHat muito bom! nao conhecia essa documentacao!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode usar o **Postfix**.

Para ter uma ideia geral do que ele faz dele acesse **[AQUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postfix_(software))**

Pagina oficial do projeto **[AQUI](http://www.postfix.org/)**

E **[AQUI](https://servidordebian.org/pt/jessie/email/start)** tem um tutorial que o usuario MagicHat indicou para sua versao de Debian

Bons estudos!